# Replace characters using regexprep in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to replace vowels in a string with another character using the function `regexprep`. For example,

```
content = regexprep( 'refrigerator', '[aeiou]', '!' )

content = r!fr!g!r!t!r
```

However, when I attempt to use a string variable in place of the character array, it does not seem to work:

```
allowedChar = 'aeiou';
content = regexprep( 'refrigerator', allowedChar, '!' )

content = refrigerator
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `[]` characters in `allowedChar`.  It should be:

```
allowedChar = '[aeiou]';
content = regexprep( 'refrigerator', allowedChar, '!' )
```

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much it!

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple substitution you could use [`ismember`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) instead of `regexprep`:

```
content(ismember(content, 'aeiou')) = '!';
```